# Как правильно реализовать ожидание activity при загрузке данных JSON

Tags: java, android, rest

В результате загрузки данных с сервера через Spring (JSON) я получаю List. И я хочу его использовать сразу после загрузки этих данных в методе onCreate(). Но если я вызываю любое действие сразу после new HttpRequestTask().execute(), система думает, что я использую пустой список, так как данные еще не загрузились. Как заставить систему ждать, пока не загрузятся данные?

```
public class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Place> listOfPlaces;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listOfPlaces = new ArrayList<>();

        new HttpRequestTask().execute();
        for (Place p : listOfPlaces) {
            System.out.println(p.getPlaceId()); //здесь ничего не выводится, так как данные еще не получены.
        }
    }

    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Example> {
        @Override
        protected Example doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final String url = "****";
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                Example example = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Example.class);
                return example;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Example example) {
            List<Place> places = example.getEmbedded().getPlace();
            listOfPlaces = places;
            System.out.println(listOfPlaces.size()); // здесь размер выводится
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну так, всё правильно. `AsyncTask`, работает **А**синхронно. т.е. в отдельном потоке. следовательно результат работы вы получите только в `onPostExecute`. Это называется коллбек.

Что происходит и почему так? Как только ваш основной поток выполняет строку  `new HttpRequestTask().execute();` он сразу пошел выполнять следующую строку, а система вам запускает второй поток в котором началась подрузка данных. затем данные вернутся в первый поток в метод `onPostExecute`.

Блокировать поток - это то чего наоборот все избегают. Если вы будете подгружать данные, вы блокируете полностью всё приложение, пока они не подгрузятся. Такое поведение не является *user friendly*. Пользователь будет видеть белый экран пока данные не подгрузятся. Если соединение с сетью слабое, то это может длиться секунд 10, пользователь будет думать что приложение зависло. Никто таким приложение пользоваться не будет. Какое решение проблемы? Решение, добавить `ProgressBar` Показывать его в начале в коллбеке AsyncTask'a `onPreExecute()` и прячете в `onPostExecute()` Пользователь будет видеть крутящийся кружок и будет ждать пока данные подгрузятся.

Собственно именно по этой причине в Android запрещены запросы в сеть в главном потоке

**UPD ответ на комментарий :**

У вас просто не получится. Любой запрос в сеть из main thread положит ваше приложение.  Правильным решением является кеширование в локальную БД.  Данные из каждого запроса в сеть пишете в базу, затем когда вы запускаете активити, данные в первую очередь берете из БД (локальная бд работает намного быстрее чем сеть) и параллельно запускаете подгрузку из сети, как данные подгрузятся пишете их базу и снова обновляете UI из базы. Таким образом пользователь сразу увидит данные (из кеша, да, они устаревшие, но пользователь уже что-то видит). И, да, тут тоже без прогресс бара никуда. Первая подрузка из БД, когда UI пустой, тоже должна сопровождаться крутящимся прогресом

**UPD после комментария @pavlofff**

Любая блокировка главного потока на длительное время приводит к появлению сообщения Application Not Responding (Приложение не отвечает), так что любые ресурсоемкие операции операции необходимо выносить в отдельный поток. Также помните, что выполняя вычисления в главном потоке вы отбираете ресурсы у отрисовки интерфейса, в результате чего приложение при скроллиге/анимациях и прочих визуальных изменениях может начать фризиться.

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение. А является ли одним из выходов загрузка данных в Splash Screen? Ведь тогда юзер не будет видеть загрузки и экран не будет "висеть"...

Comment: дополнил ответ, не бойтесь прогресс баров)

Comment: Хорошо, огромное спасибо за подробный ответ

Comment: все правильно, только вот не будет основной поток висеть секунд 10 и ждать скачивания, через 5 секунд не реагирующее на основной поток приложение закроется по ANR

Comment: @pavlofff верное замечание, писал в вольном потоке мысли и не подумал об этом, спасибо